# 2007 Chevrolet Impala over Heating

Tags: chevrolet, heater, car

I changed the radiator and thermostat completely filled it with coolant and it is over heat.

Comment: When you say "no heat at idle" are you talking about not getting any heat to the cabin of the car, or that the radiator is not getting hot?

Comment: not getting any heat to the cabin of the car

Comment: Welcome to the site: please add additional content and context to your original question text directly.  That will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your engine does not have bleed screws on the radiator cooling system. To fully top up your system, fill the radiator with coolant. Run the engine at about 2500 RPM for a couple of minutes. With a large wet rag, soaked in water, to protect your hands from any steam, slowly but slowly undo the coolant filler cap. Top up again with coolant. Do this several times until it needs no more topping up.

One Old Hands trick we use in the motor trade is to remove a component such as the coolant temperature sensor. The choice of component would be: Below the engine thermostat housing but high up on the engine block. As you fill with coolant, air will be pushed out of the system through the hole for the removed component. Once coolant starts to come out of the hole, refit the component. This trick will remove most of the air trapped in the block and get hot water more quickly to the thermostat bulb to make the final bleeding easier and quicker.

Comment: When you say "_Below_" the thermostat, do you mean "_after_"? The thermostat on my car, for example, is at the lowest height of any component in the cooling circuit. Does the trick just not work in that case?

Comment: The higher up on the engine the better. The idea behind it is that air will rise to the top of any container, but the thermostat will trap air below it. By venting high up on the engine most of any air is released.